# Can Level 29 (Hard 6x6) be solved?

Tags: flow

I have been trying to solve this puzzle for a couple of days now, and have reached the point of wondering if it can even be solved.

On Level 29, it seems like for which ever two colors I connect, the remaining one will have its path blocked:
[image: Flow, Hard, 6x6, Level 29]

The rules are simple, "pair all colors, and cover the entire board with pipe" to beat a level. Here is the previous level for illustration:
[image: Flow, Hard, 6x6, Level 28]

Can Level 29 be solved?

Comment: If it wasn't possible to solve, it wouldn't be much of a puzzle now would it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sure can be. Here's the solution (mouse over to reveal):

> [image: Screenshot of solution].

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I guess I'll keep trying, and check out your solution if I give up.

Comment: Unfortunately, spoilers don't work for images :(

Comment: If this gets a few upvotes, I'll accept it. Or I'll be sure to accept it after solving it myself.

Comment: @Louis: It's an older problem, and I love this sort of thing. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that the lines can't overlap. Does your solution avoid that?

Comment: @Louis: Yes, his does. I had the same thing ready to post about two seconds too late. :P

Comment: @MatthewScharley Spoiler tags can now be used with images if you want to - I'd edit it for you but it's not substantial enough